# Bool not updating

Tags: c#, xna

I have a bool called `attack` which I set to true whenever the `Q` button is pressed (`Q` is an attack)

I've used breakpoints to try and solve the problem myself. The line of code which sets `attack` to true is running, but it doesn't actually set `attack` to true... I'm new to XNA so sorry if this is an obvious solve. Here is the code..:  (p.s. I've left out lots of code which has nothing to do with the problem)

```
public class Player
{

    Animation playerAnimation = new Animation();

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        keyState = Keyboard.GetState()

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q))
        {
            tempCurrentFrame.Y = 0;
           *** playerAnimation.Attack = true; *** This line of code runs yet doesn't actually work
        }

public class Animation
{


    bool  attack;

public bool Attack
    {
        get { return attack; }
        set { value = attack; }
    }

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        if (active)
            frameCounter += (int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        else
            frameCounter = 0;
        if (attack) ***This never turns true***
            switchFrame = 50;
```

Like I said earlier, I've used breakpoints to check, and ALL the code does run, just nothing happens to my attack variable and I'm not sure why not.

I have a similar bool called active with all the same properties and code linked, yet that bool does get updated which is why I am so stuck.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic in the `set` accessor is backwards.  You need to assign the field `attack` to the value of the setter, not the other way around

```
set { attack = value; }
```

Comment: Can't believe I spent so much time in other places when it was such an obvious mistake. I guess that just comes with experience though. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Ralt even seasoned programmers make easy mistakes from time to time :)

Comment: Yep. Bugs like this are often the hardest to find because something so simple is not the focus of the hunt.

Comment: This is a good lesson to always start simple, even if it seems trivial. That is what I try to do, and it works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
set { value = attack; }
```

You're setting the `value` to the field, instead of the field to the value. Change it to

```
set { attack = value; }
```

Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your `set` method is backward. Try this instead.

```
set { attack = value };
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your `set` is backwards. It should be

```
set {attack = value;}
```

However, I would also like to suggest the use of Auto Properties. This would have fixed this case easily enough. It is still important to know the proper ordering of assignment, though

```
public bool Attack {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your property Getter and Setter are trivial,I suggest to implement it as Auto Property like

```
 public bool Attack{ get; set; }
```

Doing so, it will reduce your code size and yet yield the desired result.Also, the bug will have never been introduced at first place.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll implement it in to my game :)